# Matlab R2007b unresolved externals with Engine utility

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-deployment, unresolved-external, matlab-engine

I'm trying to run the matlabdemo.c provided with most copies of matlab (mine being Matlab R2007b) and despite my best efforts I keep getting "unresolved externals" errors when I try to compile the program via the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

I compiled with: "cl -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\extern\include" matlabdemo.c -link -dll -LIBPATH:"../lib/win64/microsoft/"labeng.lib"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample batch script to compile the `engdemo.c` program.

Obviously you have to adjust the paths to point to your MATLAB installation (also choose 32/64 bit versions correctly)

#### compile.bat

```
call vcvarsall.bat
set MATLABROOT=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a
cl.exe engdemo.c libeng.lib libmx.lib /Fe"engdemo" /I"%MATLABROOT%\extern\include" /link /libpath:"%MATLABROOT%\extern\lib\win32\microsoft"
```

You might need to put the MATLAB `bin` directory on the path when you run it:

```
set PATH=%MATLABROOT%\bin\win32;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to link in the MATLAB Engine libraries.  On Windows, they're called `libeng.dll` and `libmx.dll`, and they're located somewhere in the MATLAB path.  Or, use the `mex` compiler script to build your Engine programs.  Here are the two documentation links that describe those two options:

Compiling Engine Applications in an IDE:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bsru965.html

Compiling Engine Applications with the MEX command:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bsq776w-1.html